# How to censor specific fields based on condition using django QuerySet API

Tags: django, django-queryset

Using Django we have situation where we have a model `Case` which can be set to being a medical case or not (through a `BooleanField`).

Now, we also have a system to check if a certain employee (User subclass) is authorized to see sensitive data when a case is labeled as being medical (containing medical sensitive data).

I am able to `annotate` a new field to each instance, a `BooleanField` letting us know if the requesting employee is authorized to see medical data on the specific Case instance or not.

Ideally, I would like to have the database sensor out specific fields (field `customer` for example), when the requesting employee is not authorized to see medical data for that case. I imagine this can be done with an `annotate` method, and a combination of `from django.db.models.Case` and `from django.db.models.When`.

But, what we would also like is that the resulting QuerySet keeps the same field names on the different model instances. We don't want to change the field name of `customer` to another name.

We have actually come up with a solution, using `.values` first, and then the `.annotate` for each field we want to potentially censor out (see code below). This isn't ideal though, for multiple reasons. For one, we don't get back model instances, but dictionaries. Also, but this is another question, one of the fields that needs to be censored is a `ManyToManyField`, and using `.values` now returns a unique row for each instance referred to through the `ManyToManyField` (any solution for that?)

Also, ideally, this queryset would be the base queryset for all situations in which an employee tries to request Cases in our app. We want all our colleagues to use this base queryset so that we don't have to implement the same solution in multiple places, and prevent sensitive data from leaking.

So, I am wondering, can anyone recommend a solution for this situation?

Thanks in advance!

PS. We would like to have this done by the database since the amount of cases being fetched is potentially very high, and doing this in Python would probably require a lot of CPU power and thus kill performance.

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField, IntegerField, F, Value, Q


OurModel.objects.annotate(
            employee_medical_authorized=Case(
                When(..., then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )).values(...).annotate(
            customer=Case(
                When(Q(employee_medical_authorized=Value(False)) & Q(medical=Value(True)),
                     then=Value(None)),
                default=F('customer'),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
```